# ZeroMQ XPUB socket dropping packets until subscriptions arrive

Tags: zeromq

I understand an XPUB socket can drop messages that are sent on it until
it sees some forwarded subscriptions that match. Makes sense.

However, my XPUB process has restarted, and subscribers on other machines
are up and running for a while, but for a period of minutes, all messages I send
on the XPUB socket are silently dropped, until the XPUB socket receives
the forwarded client subscriptions.

I'm using a XPUB/XSUB proxy as an intermediate here. Nothing fancy here.

Is there any way to trick zmq to forward subscriptions to the new XPUB socket
which has connected to the proxy in a more timely manner?

I've thought about queuing the messages on the XPUB side until the subscription
message arrives, or perhaps implementing something in the proxy server to
cache the last subscription request, and use zmq_monitor_socket() to look for
new connections and then forward the cached subscriptions, but these both
seem kind of hacky.

Answer (score 0):

is it only the xpub thats restarted or do both xpub/xsub sockets restart, I am using nodejs zmq and in my experience my messages are still forwarded when my xpub/xsub proxy restarts..